# Django Foreign key that could contain objects of different classes

Tags: python, django, class, django-models, foreign-keys

is there a way to be able to use a foreign key to reference objects of diffrent classes

for example, this is what i'm doing :

```
Class discussion(models.Model):
    id_discussion = models.CharField(db_column='id_Discussion', primary_key=True, max_length=100)
    id_worker =   models.ForeignKey('Worker', models.CASCADE, db_column='id_user', blank=True, null=True)
    id_director = models.ForeignKey('Director', models.CASCADE, db_column='id_user', blank=True, null=True)

Class Message(models.Model):
    #some other fields
    id_sender = models.CharField(db_column='id_Sender', max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    id_receiver = models.CharField(db_column='id_Receiver', max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    id_discussion = models.ForeignKey('discussion', models.CASCADE, db_column='id_Discussion', blank=True, null=True)
```

I want to turn id_receiver and id_sender into foreign keys, my problem is that the sender could be an object of class "Worker" or of class "Director".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can use `GenericForeignKey` see here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations

NOTE: this can be pretty inefficient. Read this article to learn more about it https://lukeplant.me.uk/blog/posts/avoid-django-genericforeignkey/

Comment: Thank you ! ...  i know about GenericForeignKey but they are slow ... i'm looking for another method

Comment: @HammiCloud in mentioned article you will find alternatives